# Changing user profile of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently managing a server which has Visual Studio Code installed by a previous user. He installed the user level version and as a result, the program is under his profile:
"C:\Users\previousName\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code".

He's no longer with us and I'll be taking over the server. I was wondering how do I move this program so it's under my name? For example, the program will go to "C:\Users\meJason\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code". I want to keep whatever settings he had setup previously.

His account will be removed soon, so I'm not sure if this would remove the program from the server.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Look for a hidden folder called ".vscode" in the folder of your workspace.  Review the file called "settings.json"

Then change the appropriate file path in there.

Comment: HI Tim, I found the ".vscode" folder, but there is no "settings.json" file. I'll try reinstalling the program.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I think you need to reinstall VScode under your user.  The VScode settings are then for setting up the workspace within vscode